# Every square matrix is a sum of two diagonalisable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I've been stuck with this question for quite a while and am not sure where to start:

> Prove that if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then $A$ can be written as $B + C$ where both $B$ and $C$ have $n$ distinct eigenvalues. (Hence every square matrix is a sum of two diagonalisable matrices)

I'm thinking that maybe we can split into two triangular matrices but not sure if that's going in a right direction.

Comment: By distinct eigenvalues, do you mean that all the eigenvalues are different?

Comment: The eigenvalues of a triangular matrix are its diagonal elements.  It must be easy to adjust the diagonal elements of $B$ and $C$ to ensure they are distinct.

Comment: *"Hence every square matrix is a sum of two diagonalisable matrices"* ... a more common way to this result, $A = \frac{1}{2}\big(A+A^*\big)+\frac{1}{2}\big(A-A^*\big)$ i.e. $A$ is the sum 2 matrices, one Hermitian and one skew-Hermitian-- each are normal and hence diagonalizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Assuming you're working with real matrices, let us denote the diagonal entries as $d_1, d_2, \cdots, d_n$. All you have to do is "split" each $d_i$ into the sum of two numbers $u_i + t_i$, and ensure that all of the $u_i$ and $t_i$ are all different. This is always possible, since for any fixed real $d$ there are infinitely many pairs $(t, u)$ of real numbers such that $t + u = d$.

Note that this works because then you can just represent the matrix as the sum of an upper triangular matrix U with distinct diagonal entries and a lower triangular matrix T with distinct diagonal entries. Since the eigenvalues of such matrices are exactly the diagonal elements, and all diagonal elements are distinct by construction, we know that $U$ and $T$ are both diagonalizable, achieving your result.